# Is it OK to use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X? And, what's the dynamic library search algorithm with it?

Tags: language-agnostic, macos, dynamic-linking, dll

I read some articles discouraging of the use of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, as the the path of dynamic library should be fixed using -install_name, @rpath, and @loader_path.

In terms of making a program that runs both on Linux and Mac OS X, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH of Mac OS X does exactly what LD_LIBRARY_PATH of Linux. And, we can share (almost) the same make file that doesn't have the -install_name and @rpath.

- Is this OK to use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X?
- What's the dynamic library search algorithm with Mac OS X when the binary can't find the dynamic library? current directory -> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH directories ... ?

Comment: My recommendation would be to avoid the use of both DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH alike.  Using them at times is convenient but in my experience they are usually used incorrectly or as band-aids which tends to end up breaking things.  I'm not experienced enough with the Mac way of searching for and specifying dynamically linked libraries to fully answer your question.  Man gcc and man dyld should help you with the correct methods to use on the Mac platform.  Make -f will help if you end up having to write 2 Makefiles, one for each platform.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

As you've noted, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` behaves like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on other *nix. However, there is another environment variable you should look at called `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

In general, these are (both on osx and linux) suggested only for development use as they can cause symbol lookup errors when you override with a library that does not have the same symbol table. A good example of this is when you attempt to override the default install of VecLib (e.g. blas lapack) with a custom install. This will cause symbol not found errors in applications linked to the system VecLib if `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set and the reverse (symbol lookup errors in custom applications) if it is not. This is due to the system blas/lapack not being a full implementation of the ATLAS libs.

`DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` will not produce these problems.

When installing libraries to a non-standard location, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is much more sane. This will look for symbols in libraries provided in the default paths and if the symbol is not found there, fall back to the specified path.

The benefit is that this process will not cause symbol lookup errors in applications compiled against the default libraries.

In general, when libraries are installed to non-standard locations absolute paths should be specified which negates the ambiguity of the dynamic lookup.

Comment: Another benefit - if you set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, X11 will refuse to run. But if you set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`, you can have your custom libraries and X11 at the same time. Great answer!

Comment: Something seems fishy here: According to the docs, the default library search path is used if `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is *not* set.  Setting it will cause the default paths to be ignored, causing lots of problems.  (At least this is what I find happening with Mountain Lion.)  If you modify `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`, then it seems you must be careful to add the defaults manually. (See `man dlopen`.)  Am I missing something?

Comment: The Homebrew folks don't appreciate `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13463

Comment: DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH seems to be unusable in El Capitan cause to security reasons. Any ideas?

Comment: when installing cuda we are told to set     `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 14):

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not behave like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The OS X `dlopen` documentation (https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html) specifies that when providing an absolute path, it will first look in locations specified by `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

> When path contains a slash but is not a framework path (i.e. a full path or a partial path to a dylib),
>        dlopen() searches the following until it finds a compatible Mach-O file: $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (with leaf
>        name from path ), then the supplied path (using current working directory for relative paths), then
>        $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH (with leaf name from path ).

In other words, if you set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/Hello`, the following two `dlopen` calls:

```
dlopen("/Hello/libfoo.so", RTLD_NOW);
dlopen("/World/libfoo.so", RTLD_NOW);
```

will both resolve to `/Hello/libfoo.so`. This is quite counter-intuitive, and represents a security vulnerability. Software using `dlopen` has no way to guarantee it is loading the correct libraries (perhaps override `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in its own environment?)

Comment: A lot of times I have seen $DYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH empty, and it seems like dyld is looking for the library in my cwd. Is this a consequence of the sentence "then the supplied path (using current working directory for relative paths)", in the case that the relative path is null?

Answer (score 12):

For documentation on the dynamic link editor's environment variables and  how they affect the search for dynamic libraries, `man dyld`.

> #### DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> This is a colon separated list of directories that contain libraries. The dynamic linker searches these directories before it searches the default locations for libraries. It allows you to  test  new  versions  of  existing libraries.
>
> For  each library that a program uses, the dynamic linker looks for it in each directory in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in turn. If it still  can't  find  the  library,  it  then  searches  DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH  and  DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH in turn.
>
> Use  the  -L  option to otool(1).  to discover the frameworks and shared libraries that the executable is linked
>                 against.
>
> #### DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> This is a colon separated list of directories that contain libraries.  It is used as the  default  location  for libraries not found in their install path.  By default, it is set to $(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib.
>
> #### DYLD_VERSIONED_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> This  is  a  colon  separated list of directories that contain potential override libraries.  The dynamic linker searches these directories for dynamic libraries.  For each library found dyld looks at its LC_ID_DYLIB and gets the  current_version and install name.  Dyld then looks for the library at the install name path.  Whichever has the larger current_version value will be used in the  process  whenever  a  dylib  with  that  install  name  is required.   This  is  similar to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH except instead of always overriding, it only overrides is the supplied library is newer.

Comment: Note that `otool -L` tells you the libraries the executable is _linked_ with not necessarily the ones that will actually be loaded when it is run.  You can see this by setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and running `otool` (the paths displayed for the libraries do not take `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` into account).