# Installation error for DBD::MySQL on OSX v10.6.6

Tags: mysql, perl, osx-snow-leopard, dbi, dbd

I'm attempting to get DBD::MySQL working on Snow Leopard (v10.6.6). The default version of Perl that comes with the OS is v5.10.0. Since I've read that's 64-bit, I went ahead and downloaded and installed a 64-bit version of MySQL (mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64).

Installing and setting up MySQL went smoothly, [here's my config and version number for reference](https://gist.github.com/799201).

I used CPAN to download DBI and the DBD::MySQL drivers. I then:

- Installed DBI
- Setup a Makefile.PL
- Ran the *make* command from the command line

The Makefile.PL said it would use the following settings for compiling and testing:

```
I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config ) = -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
  embedded      (mysql_config ) = 
  libs          (mysql_config ) = -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient   -lpthread
  mysql_config  (guessed      ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default      ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default      ) = 0
  ssl           (guessed      ) = 0
  testdb        (default      ) = test
  testhost      (default      ) = 
  testpassword  (User's choice) = r00t!
  testsocket    (default      ) = 
  testuser      (User's choice) = root

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc INSTALL'.

Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/ /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 907
Using DBI 1.616 (for perl 5.010000 on darwin-thread-multi-2level) installed in /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
```

Everything seemed to be going fine, until I tried to run *make test* :

```
t/00base....................NOK 2/6#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.          
#     Error:  Can't load '/Users/swm/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.018-Pnd2qz/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Users/swm/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.018-Pnd2qz/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
#   Referenced from: /Users/swm/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.018-Pnd2qz/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
#   Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
#  at (eval 7) line 2
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 7) line 2.
FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 9
```

It's failing because it can't seem to find the mysql.bundle for DBD. Has anyone come across this problem? Or can point me in the right direction on what to try next? I need DBI/DBD::MySQL for my new job and I'm scrambling to find a solution.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

I got around the  "Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib" problem by placing a symbolic link in /usr/lib/" to /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib

Comment: I hit to an issue of _/usr/lib/_ being protected by "System Integrity Protection". Luckily _/usr/local/_ worked just fine: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib` (more details about "SIP" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734569/668194)

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the same or a similar issue. Somehow I could build and test DBD::mysql with `cpan` but when I tried to use it in a script it said things like

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Apparently, it's [a 64-bit vs 32-bit issue.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=793727)

Installing the fink [dbd-mysql-pm5100 package](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/dbd-mysql-pm5100) made it work though it took kind of a long time. I also removed the cpan-installed version:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql
sudo rm -rf /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/mysql
sudo rm -rf /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/mysql.pm
```

Answer (score 1):

also include in .profile

```
export VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=yes;
```

Besides creating the link the executions of the program with `DBI::mysql` generated an error, thus including this variable on the environment make it works

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post. But I suppose the best solution would be to add the library directory to the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH env variable. (reason here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172515/119958 )

There is no ldconfig in mac, so just add the path to this env var and rerun the install process for DBD::mysql

```
Donato-Vianas-MacBook-Pro:Invoicer donato$ cpanm DBD::mysql
--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.022.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DBD-mysql-4.022 ... OK
Building and testing DBD-mysql-4.022 ... FAIL
! Installing DBD::mysql failed. See /Users/donato/.cpanm/build.log for details.

#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 21.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/Users/donato/.cpanm/work/1359948144.491/DBD-mysql-4.022/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Users/donato/.cpanm/work/1359948144.491/DBD-mysql-4.022/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Donato-Vianas-MacBook-Pro:Invoicer donato$ export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
Donato-Vianas-MacBook-Pro:Invoicer donato$ cpanm DBD::mysql--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.022.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DBD-mysql-4.022 ... OK
Building and testing DBD-mysql-4.022 ... OK
Successfully installed DBD-mysql-4.022
1 distribution installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Donato's solution works for install, but the var has to be present at runtime as well or I get the same error. The following fixes this at runtime for shell and _www user:

```
# For command line use, add following line to ~/.bash_profile:
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH

# If Apache needs it, add following line to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
# On Lion Server, I put it after <IfDefine MACOSXSERVER>, but shouldn't matter
SetEnv DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat of an aside, but I strongly recommend setting up a separate perl on the machine -- either by fink / macports, or from source -- and leaving the Mac's system perl (and its libraries) alone.

Once I did this on my own Mac, I had very few troubles installing modules thereafter, and I didn't have to worry about accidentally blowing a hole in my OS by breaking the perl that the system uses.

If it were my Mac, I'd install a new perl from source (the Perl source distribution is smart enough to install itself see that it's on a Mac and install itself safely into /usr/local/bin) and the proceed from thee to install DBD::Mysql (and the other modules you require).

Comment: the combination of macports perl5.12 (that also installs to /usr/local/bin) and local::lib will not interfere with the system perl at all and is realy easy to set up