# snmp-net library compiled with Qt Commercial(qmake+jom) crashes

Tags: c++, qt, snmp, qmake

Application crashes when started (tried debug and release mode). Not very much experienced with this, I'll appreciate any help.

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = snmpTest5
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -LC:\snmp\lib -lnetsnmp -lnetsnmpagent  -lnetsnmpmibs
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:/snmp/include"

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>

#undef DEMO_USE_SNMP_VERSION_3

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    netsnmp_session session, *ss;
    netsnmp_pdu *pdu;
    netsnmp_pdu *response;

    oid anOID[MAX_OID_LEN];
    size_t anOID_len;

    netsnmp_variable_list *vars;
    int status;
    int count=1;

    init_snmp("snmpdemoapp");
    snmp_sess_init( &session );
    session.peername = strdup("test.net-snmp.org");

    ui->textEdit->append("test");
}
```

Application output

```
Starting ...\snmpTest5-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\debug\snmpTest5.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
...\snmpTest5-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\debug\snmpTest5.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

Compile output

```
14:22:16: Running steps for project snmpTest5...
14:22:16: Starting: "C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe" ..\snmpTest5\snmpTest5.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010
14:22:18: The process "C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
14:22:18: Starting: "C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\bin\uic.exe ..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\snmp\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"release" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Forelease\ @C:\Users\Furby\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.4600.31.jom
    C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\snmp\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"release" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -D_MSC_VER=1600 -DWIN32 ..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.h -o release\moc_mainwindow.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\snmp\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"release" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Forelease\ @C:\Users\Furby\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.4600.124.jom
mainwindow.cpp
main.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\snmp\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"release" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Forelease\ @C:\Users\Furby\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.4600.312.jom
moc_mainwindow.cpp
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(36) : warning C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(238) : see declaration of 'strdup'
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(32) : warning C4189: 'count' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(25) : warning C4101: 'response' : unreferenced local variable
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(28) : warning C4101: 'anOID_len' : unreferenced local variable
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(27) : warning C4101: 'anOID' : unreferenced local variable
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(31) : warning C4101: 'status' : unreferenced local variable
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(24) : warning C4101: 'pdu' : unreferenced local variable
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(23) : warning C4101: 'ss' : unreferenced local variable
..\snmpTest5\mainwindow.cpp(30) : warning C4101: 'vars' : unreferenced local variable
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:release\snmpTest5.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:release\snmpTest5.exe @C:\Users\Furby\AppData\Local\Temp\snmpTest5.exe.4600.2979.jom
    mt.exe /nologo /manifest release\snmpTest5.exe.embed.manifest /outputresource:release\snmpTest5.exe;1
14:22:28: The process "C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is it failing? Step into via debugger and find at which point is it generating exception? If I think correctly, it could be after you get out of `on_pushButton_clicked` function...

Comment: but on_pushButton_clicked should never be even run.. I never click the button.. basically it doesn't even show up it crashes the moment I launch it.. can't use debugger now will try tomorrow.

Comment: this question wasted my time. No relevant information about the crash available.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have setup your shared library path. An application would fail to load, inside Qt Creator, without notification if required libraries are not in PATH (in windows) environment variable or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (in linux) or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (in Mac osx - with discouraged use, but not for development. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s))

### To test this in Windows:

Check if you can run \snmpTest5.exe from the command line. If not, then use the command prompt:

set PATH=%PATH%,

then run again:
\snmpTest5.exe

Comment: Sorry, I have to learn to use "Stackoverflow" editor... the last piece of the answer must be:

Comment: Sorry, I have to learn to use "Stackoverflow" editor... the last piece of the answer must be: Check if you can run APPPATH\snmpTest5.exe from the command line. If not, then use the command prompt:

set PATH=%PATH%,APPPATH

then run again: APPPATH\snmpTest5.exe... where APPPATH is your application path.

Comment: Sorry again call to "set" must be: set PATH=%PATH%,LIBSPATH.... where LIBSPATH are your external libraries path