# dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: Image not found

Tags: macos, dylib, dyld, otool, install-name-tool

When trying to run an executable I've been sent in Mac OS X, I get the following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_atomic.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/"Directory my executable is in"
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap:5
```

I have installed the boost libraries and they are located in `/opt/local/lib`. I think the problem has something to do with the executable only looking in the directory it is in as when I paste the 'libboost_atomic.dylib' in there, it doesn't mind about it anymore. Unfortunately then it complains it can't find the next boost library.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: If you still has problem use method from this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116371/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-no-suitable-image-found/43466989#43466989)

Comment: Try to uninstall python3.7.3 using this:- https://huybien.com/how-to-completely-uninstall-python-on-macos/

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Find all the boost libraries (where `exefile` is the name of your executable):

```
$ otool -L exefile
exefile:
        @executable_path/libboost_something.dylib (compatibility version 0.7.0, current version 0.7.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 65.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

and for each `libboost_xxx.dylib`, do:

```
$ install_name_tool -change @executable_path/libboost_something.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_something.dylib exefile
```

and finally verify using `otool` again:

```
$ otool -L exefile
exefile:
        /opt/local/lib/libboost_something.dylib (compatibility version 0.7.0, current version 0.7.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 65.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Manpages: [`otool`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/otool/) [`install_name_tool`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/install_name_tool/)

**EDIT** A while back I wrote a python script (`copy_dylibs.py`) to work out all this stuff automatically when building an app.  It will package up all libraries from `/usr/local` or `/opt/local` into the app bundle and fix references to those libraries to use `@rpath`.  This means you can easily install third-party library using Homebrew and package them just as easily.

I have now made this script public on [github](https://github.com/trojanfoe/xcodedevtools).

Comment: @trojanfoe can you please explain here what is the exefile is it be a tool exec file path ? isnt it ?

Comment: After recompiling the executable I have to repeat this process - quite annoying during development.

Comment: Actually the better way is to use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to modify the search path. The other answer has got this.

Comment: 'exefile': No such file or directory

Comment: @ScottyBlades `exefile` stands for the executable file you're trying to run. In my case, `otool -L /usr/local/bin/php` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me when Homebrew messed up bash. In my case I needed to run `install_name_tool` as root to get over the issue. This one-liner inspects all the dylibs for a binary: `otool -L /usr/local/bin/bash | awk -F' ' '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | xargs -I{} ls {}`

Comment: Here's the other way. Please take a look. https://github.com/eXolnet/homebrew-deprecated/issues/27

Comment: @YuAnShaolinMaculelêLai Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @frankliuao - Which answer exactly is the "other answer"?

Comment: @SecurityHound [This is the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35027026/2988929).

Comment: Using DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't seem to work for me. Thankfully install_name_tool does.

Answer (score 169):

This worked for me:

```
brew upgrade node
```

Comment: What is this doing, though?

Comment: @diegoaguilar this is reinstalling `node` using homebrew. Probably another installation broke node path. Also worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me after updating macOS Catalina. Thanks!

Comment: Same here, I fixed it with `brew upgrade node` (OSX Catalina)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Save most people a lot of hassle.

Comment: @JeremyMoritz Except that the question doesn't even mention `node` and is not tagged with `node`.  It's an answer to a different question.

Comment: This worked for my  Mac OSX Catalina

Answer (score 126):

In the target's `General` tab, there is a section called `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`

Click on the `+` sign, add required `framework` and the crash is resolved.

[image: Update latest xcode screen-shot]

Comment: what should i add ? there's a lot of files

Comment: @Himanshu I have libcppreset for my project! it has a lot of dependency from boost and ...
I run a bash script to change them with install_name_tool but for the `LC_ID_DYLIB` I can't so need to make a symlink in usr/loca/opt !
is there any way to figure out ? :| 
It's painfull :(

Comment: Add the framework and set the framework to `Embed & Sign`

Comment: I just removed and added again the library and it worked

Answer (score 117):

After upgrade Mac OS to Mojave. I tried to install npm modules via `yarn` command I got error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.60.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Was fixed with:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Comment: My intelliJ started throwing this error when I recently updated xcode.
I was trying to run a node.js server through intellij.
I wasn't sure what went wrong. Running `node --version` on my system resulted in the same error.
Running the above two commands solved my problem.

Comment: In my case, I also ran the `brew cleanup` command, which is good to do at times if you want to get rid of old versions.

Comment: Regarding to @MichaelBehrens's comment, I run  `brew cleanup` then it fixed.

Answer (score 45):

For some, this could be as easy as setting the system path for dynamic libraries.  On OS X, this is as simple as setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  See:

[Is it OK to use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X? And, what's the dynamic library search algorithm with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s)

Comment: It may seem stupid, but I wonder what value should I set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to?

Comment: @Caesar Set it to the directory of wherever the dylibs you're trying to link are located.

Comment: You cannot expect your users to change `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  The correct solution is to include non-standard libraries with the `.app` and the user won't have to do anything.  The developer, however, may still have to hack the loader path as per my answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe .app? Have a test executable, trying to link some .dylib . Linux is same with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: So easy. Thank you! Wonder, what other answers are about, and how brew would do a similair thing ...

Answer (score 42):

this should fix the issue

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
```

Comment: Using this worked for me, unfortunately, I still don't know what  cause of the issue to begin with or why updating, upgrading and cleaning up solve the issue

Comment: this worked totally for me, however, while trying to do the cleanup, i ran into some permission issue, if you also have this trouble, try running 
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib then try running the brew cleanup again

Comment: I still get `ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/Users/foo/.local/share/virtualenvs/TMIWqqTS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)
` after running this

Comment: I fixed my follow up error by reinstalling python. I use asdf to manage my language versions so I did `asdf uninstall python 3.7.3` (I was using 3.7.3, specify here the version you have) and then ran `asdf install python 3.7.3`.

Comment: if till not work :  brew services start php

Comment: I had to follow this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72820874/3342981

Answer (score 12):

I got this error when I tried to install ruby 2.3.1 using rvm. It first told me to run `brew update`, which I did, and then when I tried running `rvm install ruby-2.3.1`, I received the error in this SO question.

The fix was to first run `brew upgrade`, apparently according to this [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1096438/brew-upgrade-broke-vim-on-os-x-dyld-library-not-loaded) question you need to do both `brew update` && `brew upgrade`. Once that was done, I could finally install ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: People need to stop recommending doing `brew upgrade` just like that. This can be a massive disruptor for one's entire system. Instead, isolate what needs to be upgraded and upgrade that only.

Answer (score 12):

Now that Xcode has upgraded their IDE, they have changed a little bit how this functions.

It used to be split up into separate section as demonstrated above with 'Embedded Binaries' and 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' as separate sections.

Now, it is one combined section with drop-downs on the right as to what should be embedded.

[image: New IDE Changes]

This was confusing to me at first, but makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 11):

**If you're using Xcode 11 onwards:**

Go to `General` tab and add the framework in `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` section.

**Important:** By default it might be marked as `Do Not Embed`, change it to `Embed Without Signing` like shown in the image and you are good to go.

[image]

**For Xcode versions below 11:**

Just add the framework in `Embedded Binaries` section and you are done.

Cheers!

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case choosing "Embed & Sign" worked.

Comment: Yes it depends on the library if it was signed by the developer or not. Most of the times frameworks are not signed. But there may be cases when these are signed. I also had to select 'Embed & Sign' for a Google framework.

Answer (score 10):

To resolve the error below on my Macbook Catalina 10.15.4:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
    Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongoexport
    Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I ran the command below and got round the problem above:

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

Comment: any explanations on this would be helpful.

Comment: Looks to me like the executable shouldn't even be linking against `libssl.1.0.0.dylib`, but rather `libssl.1.dylib`, which will be symlinked to the exact version on the system while maintaining API compatibility. See [this](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/als00/2000papers/papers/full_papers/browndavid/browndavid_html/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [otool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) command with the -L option for the executable, which will display where the executable is expecting those libraries to be.

If the path to those need changing, use the [install_name_tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html) command, which allows you to set the path to the libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Making the Frameworks in the Build Phases **Optional** worked for me.

> In Xcode -> Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries ->
> Make sure the newly added frameworks if any are marked as Optional

Answer (score 5):

I got here trying to run a program I just compiled using CMake. When I try to run it, it complains saying:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/path/to/my/executable
  Reason: image not found
```

I circumvented the problem telling CMake to use the static version of Boost, instead of letting it use the dynamic one:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

Answer (score 3):

I fix it by `brew install libpng`

Answer (score 3):

If you use cmake, add `DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE "@rpath"` to target properties:

```
set_target_properties(target_dyLib PROPERTIES
        # # for FRAMEWORK begin
        # FRAMEWORK TRUE
        # FRAMEWORK_VERSION C
        # MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.cmake.targetname
        # MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST ./Info.plist
        # PUBLIC_HEADER targetname.h
        # # for FRAMEWORK end
        IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "8.0"
        DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE "@rpath" # this is the key point
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
        DEVELOPMENT_TEAM "${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM}"
    )
```

or in Xcode dynamic library project **Target -> Build Setting** set **Dynamic Library Install Name Base** to **@rpath**

Comment: I create a cocoa framework dynamic library project, it works,  and compared with my bad cmake generated project find this different, and fixed it, it works on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by using `Product > Clean Build Folder` (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>), which makes a new clean build, really odd.

Answer (score 3):

For my framework I was using an Xcode subproject added as a git submodule.

I believe I was getting this error because I was signing the framework with a **different signing Team** than my main app. (switched teams for app; forgot to switch for framework)

Solution is to *not* sign within the framework project. Instead, in the main app's `Target > General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` section, sign the framework via `Embed & Sign`.

If I select `Do not Embed` or `Embed Without Signing` I instead get the error:

> *FRAMEWORK* not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sudo install_name_tool -change` change dylib path
And
`sudo install_name_tool -id` change dylib name

Answer (score 2):

### Xcode 11.1 & Swift 5.1

### Quick Fix

***First make sure that external added library has option embed is selected in General Tab, Embbed Binaries.***

If still not works..

This happens because you have different, unmatched versions of libraries present.

**Update the Pods**

```
pod update
```

*Important: Check all libraries are included in the Build Settings -> libraries and frameworks list and you have given option to embbed in the build*

Just working awesome

Answer (score 2):

if you use virtualenv just remove the folder of your environment and recreate it with this command
`virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 the_name_of_my_env`

Answer (score 2):

In our case, it's an iOS app, built on Xcode 11.5, using cocoapods (and cocoapods-binary if you will).

We were seeing this crash:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/PINOperation.framework/PINOperation
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4C5F5E4C-8B71-4351-A0AB-C20333544569/Tellus.app/Frameworks/PINRemoteImage.framework/PINRemoteImage
  Reason: image not found
```

Turns out that I had to delete the pods cache and re-run pod install, so Xcode would point this diff:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this page because they got this error trying to link a third party framework to their project using Xcode 6.3.1, the problem I ran into was because the library was being created with an older version of the compiler using a different version of swift.  The only way to fix this for me was to re-build the framework.

Another reason you might get this is stated in an Apple technical doc..

> If you are building an app that does not use Swift but embeds content such as a framework that does, Xcode will not include these libraries in your app. As a result, your app will crash upon launching with an error message looking as follows:

set the Embedded Content Contains Swift Code (EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT) build setting to YES in your app

Here is the link to the full Apple doc that explains it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1881/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same thing with a different library or package, @user3835452 is on the right track. I found this message while trying to run `composer`:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

After trying a lot of different ways I just ran `brew install openldap` and it fixed it. Note that I had already ran `brew update` and `brew upgrade` but only after I manually installed `openldap` did it actually work.

Comment: I had a similar problem dyld: Library not loaded:/usr/local/opt/fftw/lib/libfftw3f.3.dylib. After checking many possible solutions I just did brew install fftw and it worked for me. Thanks @brunouno

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to fix this?

I just used `brew upgrade <the tool>`. In my case, `brew upgrade tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was node that was out of date, you need to upgrade it after goin up to BigSur - brew upgrade node

Answer (score 1):

As said in https://gist.github.com/berkedel/d1fc6d13651c16002f64653096d1fded, you could try

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
brew install node
brew link --overwrite node
```

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Fix**

- Remove the pod (whose name is in the error) by commenting it in your Podfile, like #Podname
- Run `pod install`
- Uncomment the pod that you commented earlier
- Run `pod install` again.

It worked for me and is easy to do so sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the app crash issue quoting SIGABRT error in thread.Overview of the crash is dyld library not loaded and image not found something  like that.

This was seen in Xcode 9.3. The reason I found out was Xcode is not picking up libraries dynamically so I had to do it manually which solved my crash issue.

Follow the below steps:

1. Go to Build Phases
2. Hit the '+' button at the top and select "New Copy File Phase"
3. Select Destination as Frameworks and Hit the '+' button below to add files.
4. Select Add Other at below, click CMD+SHIFT+G and paste the below path,
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos`

Now you will be able to see some swift dylibs, Select all the swift libraries with .dylib extension and click on open.

These will get added to the embedded binaries in the general tab of app.

Create a new group in project folder and add all these libraries.

Now run your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Conda environment in the terminal, update the samtools to solve it.

> > conda install -c bioconda samtools

Answer (score 0):

Best one is answered above first check what is the output of

otool -L

And then do the following if incorrect

```
set_target_properties(
    MyTarget
    PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS
    "@executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks"
)
```

And

```
set_target_properties(
        MyTarget
        PROPERTIES
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE 
        "@rpath"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after using asdf to switch my python version. When you activate the virtualenv it gets confused.

Instead recreate the virtualenv like so

```
$ rm -rf venv
$ python -m venv venv
```

This time when you activate the virtualenv it will find the correct python.

Answer (score 0):

It is an **dynamic linker** error which links binary in load or runtime

[[@rpath]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216681/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Select your project
2. Go To Targets
3. Go To Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content
4. Click at the + icon
5. You should get a prompt => Search for your missed library; -in my case was OpenSSL-.
6. Select it and add it.
7. clean your project.
8. Re-build.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**: This approach cleared this up for me with ease ...

My particular CLI tool that triggered the same issue (i.e., netdiscover), was looking for:

/usr/local/opt/libnet/lib/**libnet.1.dylib**

When I searched that path for, **libnet.1.dylib**, **ls** returned a file, but a newer version: **libnet.9.dylib**

Following the approach presented in this article, [How to Fix ‘Dyld: Library not Loaded’ Error on MacOS](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-on-macos/), I was able to fix the issue by simply creating a symlink pointer to the file that the tool was looking for (i.e., **libnet.1.dylib**), to that of the new file version listed on my system (i.e., **libnet.9.dylib**), ...

ln -s /usr/local/opt/libnet/lib/**libnet.9.dylib** /usr/local/opt/libnet/lib/**libnet.1.dylib**

... now when I run the tool, it finds the dependancies it needs without complaint!, : )

**--AA**

Reference:

Answer (score 0):

This was my reason of the issue:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/AVFAudio   Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6724E76-E704-46A2-8637-F43277018CE2/MyFrameworkUsageSample.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework Reason: image not found dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

I was creating own framework MyFramework - where the Apple Framework was used. And build the xcframework with latest deployment target - iOS 16. While in the TestApp required to run on iOS 13+. And The Test Devices were using iOS 15.

Thus the TestApp with MyFramework was launching on Simulator (iOS16) successfully. But not on the Devices.

Resolution: In MyFramework - change the deployment target to needed iOS. And re-generate your framework. Or if you are using the 3d-party framework - ask the provider to support you minimal deployment target.

So missed to change the min deployment target in the xcframework before building - and Apple logs were as usual super helpful)))

Answer (score 0):

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath new_path executable
install_name_tool -delete_rpath old_path  executable
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Removing older php version is fixed my problem, like:

```
 brew remove php@7.4
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was Target A, Target B and pod. Target A embedding target B. Target B has in podfile lib `Alamofire`.

If Target A not having Alamofire in Podfile, there was an error.

To fix it, I had to add `pod Alamofire` into Target A and Target B the both. Despite Target A not using Alamofire.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by reinstalling Homebrew

Uninstall

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

Install

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score -1):

For anyone that might still be having this problem:

This is an ongoing problem on Apple's side, and what worked for me is upgrading to ios 13.4(beta). Installed that and worked like a charm.

Comment: this is not IOS issue.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to add use_frameworks! in my podfile. I added it back and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

None of the above worked for me, but `brew reinstall icu4c` did.