# Matlab - dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mpfr2/lib/libmpfr.1.dylib

Tags: matlab, gcc, dyld

I am trying to compile a matlab program using mex. I am facing the following error and was wondering if you have any suggestions. I have installed latest version of mpfr at `/usr/local/opt/mpfr` but it is still picking `/usr/local/opt/mpfr2`.

The error is as below:

> **dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mpfr2/lib/libmpfr.1.dylib**
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/cc1plus
>     **Reason: Incompatible library version: cc1plus requires version 4.0.0 or later, but libmpfr.1.dylib provides version 3.0.0**
>   g++-4.8: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1plus)
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/mex: line 1326: 15075 Abort trap: 6           /usr/local/bin/g++-4.8 -c -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fno-common -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O2 -DNDEBUG "face-detection/src/resizef.cc" -o face-detection/private/resizef.o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: Image not loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded)

Answer (score 2):

Try running this command before compiling:

```
setenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH','')
```

I was trying to compile something else (not a Matlab program) and received the same error. The same command worked in bash, so I inspected the environment variables and found that Matlab's DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH differed from bash's DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. The bash DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was not defined, so I set it to empty in Matlab and it fixed the path error.

Matlab's setenv documentation:

> Values assigned to variables using setenv are picked up by any
>   process that is spawned using the MATLAB SYSTEM, UNIX, DOS or '!'
>   functions. You can retrieve any value set with setenv by using
>   GETENV(NAME).

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling `gcc` and its `mpfr2` package, e.g.:

```
brew reinstall gcc48 mpfr2
```

Also make sure you're not overriding any `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` variables from the startup shell scripts (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`).