# Cannot use MySQLdb in python (newbie)

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

After downloading MySQLdb from sourceforge here, I ran setup.py to install it.  Now when I try to import "MySQLdb" I get the following error:

```
 >>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm new to python so I'm not really sure what this means.  Can anybody help me figure out how to alleviate this error?  Thank you!!!

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded

Comment: It seems that you need to install libmysqlclient18 with your system package manager. On Ubuntu, run ``sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18``

Answer (score 2):

You need the mysql client library to build `MySQLdb`. The easiest way that I know of to install it in Mac OS X is to get [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then install `mysql` with:

```
brew install mysql
```

Extra bonus - you can easily install python 3 using brew as well.