# Qtcreator libraries on imac dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: qt5

I have an error when i try to execute my app with `QTCreator 5` :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /projets/mcs_control/QT5/build-mcs_control-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit-Debug/mcs_control.app/Contents/MacOS/mcs_control
  Reason: image not found
```

My libraries installation directory is not the same. How to fix this problem ?

Regards, 
laurent

Answer (score 3):

I found two ways of solving this problem.

First, the ugly one:

```
ln -s /Users/MYUSERNAME/Qt/5.2.0/clang_64/ /usr/local/Qt-5.2.0
```

`/Users/MYUSERNAME/Qt` is place where I installed Qt.

Other way is by using **otool** and **install_name_tool**. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17704255/3162977) helped greatly.

Comment: Perfect. For me, this looked more like:
       ln -s /Users/MYUSERNAME/QtSrc/5.7.1/Src/qtbase /usr/local/Qt-5.7.1

For additional reference, run qmake inside the location, running: qmake -query