# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib Referenced from:<Framework> Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, xcode-workspace

I've created a Cocoa Touch Framework to centralize my common Swift code and moved some things into it-- and now I'm using it in my other Swift project, in a workspace.  At first the main project compiled, but upon startup I got this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-guvhnmqtcqhmmndemyhztmwxbkjq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JBS.framework/JBS
>   Reason: image not found

I've found that can fix it by turning on the option **Embedded Content Contains Swift Code** in the framework, but then I get a bunch of duplicate symbols in the log, like so:

> objc[19237]: Class GGLBundleUtil is implemented in both
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-guvhnmqtcqhmmndemyhztmwxbkjq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JBS.framework/JBS
>   and
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CCAD7FCA-BF5F-428A-8122-680B91300618/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/22DC1E4F-B631-450A-A157-A6ADA0126DE6/AppName.app/AppName.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I don't think I'm supposed to turn on the Embedded Content Contains Swift Code option in the framework, but I don't know why the framework can't find the Swift libraries.  Anyone?

**Edit:**

When I try to run the app on the device, I get a similar but different error.  It seems to be complaining that it can't see my framework:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/JBS.framework/JBS   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C7644037-E5A0-431E-A7DB-D3B124CDC677/AppName.app/AppName
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116371/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-no-suitable-image-found/43466989#43466989). The same topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that when I tried to add the framework into the Embedded Binaries, I didn't pay good enough attention to the section names.

Instead I added it into the section which had the other Linked Frameworks and Libraries, because there were some other ones there already.  Once I added it into the Embedded Binaries section (which also re-added it back to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries when I did) it no longer gave me the main error as seen in the title.

I still as of yet, however, haven't figured out how to solve the duplicate symbols error, which occurs all the time now even though Embedded Content Contains Swift Code is turned off everywhere.  But that wasn't the main issue in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test it in device? If so, the bundle id must be the same between your project and your framework.

Comment: Because you asked, I tried it on the device and it behaves differently.  It refuses to work even with the Embedded Content Contains Swift Code turned on, saying the same "dyld: Library not loaded:".  The bundle id of the framework is different than the project, but as far as I can tell it needs to be so I can load the bundles distinctly as needed.

Comment: Actually, the error is a little bit different on the device.  It's the same kind of error, but it's complaining it can't find my framework, rather than the framework not finding Swift frameworks.