# Error manually adding framework required by another framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-pop

I'm trying to implement this wonderful framework: https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

The framework requires `Facebook Pop`, I don't like using cocoa pod so I added `Pop` manually, like this:

[image]
[image]

And I linked `Pop` to `Koloda`, `Koloda` to main project.

I succeeded running on simulator, but When I ran **on iPhone**, after the app launches, the compiler says:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/pop.framework/pop
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9FC4B4D6-35AE-4233-9873-13905A64F725/Memory
>   Alarm.app/Frameworks/Koloda.framework/Koloda
>   Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Big thanks to @kamal and @JingJingTao for trying so hard to help me with this problem, I solved eventually with Cocoa Pods.

There seems to be some code signing issue with Xcode 7, which is marked out in Xcode 8, unfortunately I wasn't able to use Xcode 8 to build due to the other libraries need upgrade, this problem seem to be very common: 
[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib)

**Eventually, as @JingJingTao suggested, I had to try Cocoa Pods, and it worked, guess for now, it's the only solution.**

Last thoughts, Cocoa Pods has an open community, people discuss and fix almost every issue you can encounter, while with Xcode, when you are freaking out with a problem, no one will tap on your shoulder and say: "Hey this is a bug and we will fix it later. " because, they are not open source.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7.3.1. Base SDK 9.3 . I was able to compile and run project by manually adding Kolada and Facebook pop. I am not sure if you tried adding Kolada as Embedded project. (Available since ios8). Here are steps I followed:

1. Right click on my project to add "Kolada".
2. Right click on Kolada to add Facebook Pop.
   2.1. Make sure Facebook Pop is added in General -->Linked Framework and    Libraries. 
   2.2 And in Build Phases --> Add Copy Files Phase. Make destination as Framework and Add pop.framework here.
3. Add Kolada as Embedded project . Select your project Target . General --> Embedded Binaries.

Following questions might be helpful to you:

[Reason: no suitable image found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found)

[dyld: Library not loaded. Reason : no suitable image found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116371/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-no-suitable-image-found)

I am attaching screenshots.

[Adding Kolada to Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjean.png)

[image]

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: I think I did the same way, except your `pop` framework looks a little different from mine.

Comment: do you mean structure of project is different? or the way it is added. I downloaded zip file from https://github.com/facebook/pop and then added the xcode project to Koloda.

Comment: actually the icon, I'll try re-download it and add again.

Comment: How do you add `pop` without deleting the red `pop` framework?

Comment: Sorry.. not sure if I understood question. I do not think you need to worry about red color pop framework. you do not need to delete it.

Comment: Did you try running on real device? I succeeded on simulator, but failed on my iPhone.

Comment: Apologies for  somehow missed point that you were able to run on simulator. I also had similar issue as you running on device. I tried a lot yesterday to make it work. I was not successful but sharing my experience.  I thought might be helpful to you. I made some edits to my answer. As well as I found several other Posts with similar error. It might just be bug in xcode. Hence It will be worthwhile to try it on xcode 8 beta.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've added pop to Koloda, you then can add the iOS framework for pop to Koloda, it should appear at the top of the list. Does the Koloda project compile? [image: framework]

Comment: Can you continue this in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Comment: Sorry I'm in GMT time, going to sleep now, can I talk to you later?

Comment: No worries, I'm in GMT time, it's 3pm, we can try pick this up later.

Comment: Sure! It's 10 pm here :)

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, the problem is still there? Are you able to help me out?

Comment: Obvious thing to try, delete the app on the iPhone, do a clean and reinstall the app. If it works on the simulator it should work on the device in this case.

Comment: Tricky, can I suggest you try cocoapods :p, it's worth learning if you have the time. I can try look into this problem more.