# Why am I getting this bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('?

Tags: c++, bash, terminal, osx-yosemite

I am testing C++ boost library and I am trying to recompile my dynamic libs. In order to do that I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded) and I am getting terminal error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

This is the script I used

```
venushkas-MacBook-Pro:~ venushka$ otool -L exefile:@executable_path/ dyliblibboost_atomic.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0) /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0) /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

I have simply changed all the white spaces of above script but nothing works for me. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try backslashing your parentheses.

Comment: The answer in the link tells you a generic way of running the command. The command is `otool -L exefile`, where exefile should be replaced by the executable file you are trying to run. The remaining is the output of that command.

Comment: Please try to understand what you are copying / pasting, rather than just copying & pasting.

Answer (score 4):

This is the command

```
otool -L exefile
```

Everything else in that link is output from the command.

Comment: @VenushkaT: stop writing all the stuff after the `otool -L executable`.  If you must write it (I can't think why; the man page doesn't suggest it would do anything useful), then you must enclose the arguments with parentheses inside quotes, or use backslashes in front of the parentheses.  But it doesn't seem likely to do anything useful for you; it certainly doesn't for me on my Mac.