# happygrep - dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib

Tags: macos, grep, ncurses, dylib, homebrew-cask

I'm trying to run CLI happygrep on my Mac OS X 10.9. but an error occured:
**happygrep - dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib**.

I install it like this:

```
  $ brew cask update
  $ brew cask install happygrep
```

Can someone help me ? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: Image not loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded)

Answer (score 7):

Reinstalling `ncurses` package should help, e.g.

```
brew reinstall ncurses
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggled, I find a way to solve it:

1. Why error: because CLI happygrep need ncursesw-related lib to support.
2. Install ncursesw-related lib:

   ```
   $ brew search ncurses
   homebrew/dupes/ncurses 
   $ brew install homebrew/dupes/ncurses
   ```
3. After that, run CLI **happygrep 'key-word'**.

   [See this -happygrep usage](https://github.com/happypeter/happygrep).

Comment: `brew install homebrew/dupes/ncurses` yields the following message `Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`, so it's no longer actual.