# Loading symbols from so file and calling method

Tags: c++, xcode, shared-libraries

I have a problem in C++.

I've created a function called execute

```
int* execute(int tab[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            if (tab[j] > tab[j+1])
            {
                int tmp = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tab[j+1];
                tab[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

So, this is simple BubbleSort function. I have this function in file BubbleSortAlgorithm.cpp.

So, in main function of my program, I check if libBubbleSortAlgorithm.so exist. If not, then I must create this lib. This lib is created via popen. So I've ended up with file libBubbleSortAlgorithm.so. If I run command

```
nm libBubbleSortAlgorithm.so | c++filt
```

then I get something like this.

```
0000000000000ed0 T execute(int*, int)
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

I presume this is ok. So, next in main program, I load this .so file in my program with dlopen and call this function like this

```
void *handle = dlopen(buff, RTLD_LAZY);
if (handle)
{
    execute = dlsym(handle, "execute");
    int tab[5] = { 5, 2, 4, 7, 1 };
    int x = 5;
    execute(tab, x);
}
```

But before main I've also wrote this

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void (*execute)(int*, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

So, in Xcode7, I get this error:
/Users/Tadej/Documents/Development/ALGatorC_final/ALGatorC/ALGatorC/main.cpp:96:49: Assigning to 'void (*)(int *, int)' from incompatible type 'void *'

Thank you in advance for help.

Regards,
golobich

*Edit: I've changed code like this:*

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    int* (*execute)(int*, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


execute = (int*(*)(int*, int))dlsym(handle, "execute");
int tab[5] = { 5, 2, 4, 7, 1 };
int x = 5;
int *xs = execute(tab, x);
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    std::cout << xs[i] << ", ";
}
```

So, now, I have problem at runtime. At execute(tab, x), Xcode complain and say this: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0). So, problem is that execute is NULL. Any help? :)

Comment: I think you need to cast the return from dlsym to the correct type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely cast the result.

dlsym just returns a (function) pointer, but does not know (nor it can) know the actual signature of your function. Only client code (your) can know that.

Cast can be done like this:

```
typedef int *(*execute_t)(int, int) ;
...
execute = (execute_t *)dlsym(handle, "execute");
```

And keep in mind what @molbdnilo says about function to be declared 'extern "C". This has to be done in libary code, not on client side

```
extern "C" int* execute(int tab[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
....
```

Comment: I've edit my question and changed the code. Can you take a look at code again? I would appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This was very helpful! :) I've accepted your answer. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The function in the library wasn't compiled with `extern "C"` linkage, so the name has C++ name-mangling in the library.
Because of this, `dlsym` can't find the name "execute" and returns a null pointer.

Either add `extern "C"` in the library, or `dlsym` the actual symbol as shown by `nm` *without* piping its output through `c++filt`.
Or build your library from C code.

Comment: Ok, so, this is from nm command: 0000000000000ed0 T __Z7executePii In code, than I said `execute = (int*(*)(int*, int))dlsym(handle, "__Z7executePii");` And it's still NULL. And another question. Will this symbol name __Z7executePii be the same on any computer?

Comment: The mangled form of a name is compiler-specific and very non-portable. I would try compiling with C linkage for that function (add `extern "C"`, or just compile as C) to see if that works, then verifying that the library is built with the correct options if it doesn't.

Comment: If I say `extern "C" int* execute(int*, int) { ... }` then I get this linker error in Xcode
duplicate symbol _execute in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Development/ALGatorC_final/ALGatorC/DerivedData/ALGatorC/Build/Intermediates/ALGatorC.build/Debug/ALGatorC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/.../Documents/Development/ALGatorC_final/ALGatorC/DerivedData/ALGatorC/Build/Intermediates/ALGatorC.build/Debug/ALGatorC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BubbleSortAlgorithm.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: And by the way, I want my file that has BubbleSort function to be .cpp because it will contain some class. I compile that cpp file with g++.

Answer (score 0):

I had same Problem but I did the following, without using the **extern "C" keyword**. Let say, we create a directory in **Users/you/Desktop/FooProject** and we write our shared library **foo.cpp** :

```
    #ifndef FOO_H
    #define FOO_H

    int sum(int x, int y)
    {
       return x+y;
    }

    int subs( int x, int y)
    {
        return x-y;
    }

    #endif //FOO_H
```

We create the share library from **foo.cpp**:

```
          g++ -dynamiclib foo.cpp -o libfoo.dylib
```

Now we would like to write a program that gets the function pointers to our library in the same directory **/Users/You/FooProject/**. For that we use **dlopen()**, **dlsym()** and **dlclose()** functions.

Because of the C++ name-mangling (used for function overloading ) our function names will differ from the ones that we have written on **foo.cpp**.

If we run **objdump** **-t** **libfoo.dylib** we get ( on my machine) this output:

```
        libfoo.dylib:   file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

        SYMBOL TABLE:
        0000000000000f80 g     F __TEXT,__text  __Z3sumii
        0000000000000fa0 g     F __TEXT,__text  __Z4subsii
    0000000000000000         *UND*  dyld_stub_binder
```

Here is the tricky thing to take in count. Notice the two underscore lines before the names **__Z3sumii** and **__Z4subsii**. The actual names of the functions that we want to pull are just with one underscore instead of two. The names of the functions are **_Z3sumii** and **_Z4subsii** with only one underscore.

If you try to pull out the functions on **dlsym()** passing the name with the two underscores or the original names it will return **NULL**.

**Wrong:**

```
 int (*sum)(int, int);
 sum = dlsym(foo_lib_handle,"__Z3sumii");//two underscores and no casting

 or

 int (*sum)(int, int);
 sum = dlsym(foo_lib_handle,"sum"); //the name demangled and no casting
```

**Correct:**

```
  int (*sum)(int, int);
  sum = ( int(*)(int, int) ) dlsym(foo_lib_handle,"_Z3sumii");
```

Because the dlsym returns a void pointer and the signatura expected is different we need to cast it appropriately.

Now that we know the names we need. We can write the code to pull out the function pointers for the dylib, called **pullout.cpp**:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

 int main( )
 {   
   //function pointers for the pulled functions
   int (*sum)(int, int);
   int (*subs)(int, int);

   // open the shared library
   void* foo_lib_handle = dlopen("libfoo.dylib", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);

   if(!foo_lib_handle)
   {
       std::cout << "problemo loading dylib" << std::endl;
       return 1;
   }

   //notice the casting and the name "_Z3sumii" instead of "__Z3sumii" and the same for subs
   sum  = ( int(*)(int, int) ) dlsym(foo_lib_handle,"_Z3sumii"); 
   subs = ( int(*)(int,int ) ) dlsym(foo_lib_handle,"_Z4subsii");

   if( sum == NULL || subs == NULL )
   {

      std::cout << "functions pointers are null" << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   std::cout << "calling sum(8,8) = " << sum(8,8) << '\n';
   std::cout << "calling subs(18,8) = "<< subs(18,8) <<'\n';

   //close the library
   dlclose(foo_lib_handle);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile **pullout.cpp**:

```
   g++ -c pullout.cpp
```

To Link the **pullout.o** file generated, we can use several approaches :

1. We can use the **-L** to specify the path where to search the lib, and **-l** :

   ```
     g++ pullout.o -L. -lfoo -o pulloutFoo
   ```

   The **-l** option is expanded as **-libfoo.dylib**. Is important to notice that the default search path for gcc are:

   ```
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/lib
   ```

Because of this, we need to use the **-L** option followed by the path. In our case we use the current directory.

2. Second option is to specify the full path and the name of the lib, so we do not have to use te **-L**, and **-l** options.

   ```
           g++ pullout.o libfoo.dylib -o pullFoo
   ```
3. Third option, put the shared library into one of the common directories like **/usr/local/lib** . Then we would just do :

   ```
           g++ pullout.o -lfoo -o pullFoo
   ```

If we run it:

```
  $ ./pullFoo
  calling sum(8,8) 16 
  calling subs(18,8) 10
```

**Extra:**

For runtime problems, see install names for mac os here: [dynamic libraries](https://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/dynamic-libraries,-rpath,-and-mac-os) and macOs and here [stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded).