# Error while trying to run rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I keep getting this error while trying to run a rails server

```
   dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
   Referenced from: /Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby
   Reason: image not found
   Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have tried these and I still get the error

```
         brew update && brew install gmp && rvm reinstall 2.1.4
```

I have also added Xcode & Command Line Tools for mac and still I am having the same issue.

Dose anyone know how to solve this issue?  Please let me know if you require any more information to help solve this issue.

Comment: Looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded. See if that helps.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out, I did not see that while searching a fix!