# unsafe use of relative rpath libboost.dylib when making boost.python helloword demo?

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost

Recently, I am learning boost C++ library. I want to use python to call exist C++ project. I have install boost under OSX 10.11 using `brew install boost`. My python version 2.7.

I make a hello.c:

```
char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

and Makefile:

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)

# location of the Boost Python include files and library
#  
BOOST_INC = /usr/local/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/local/lib
#   
# compile mesh classes
TARGET = hello

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).c
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).c
```

However, after I run `make` and got hello.so. I met following error when I run python code:

```
import hello
print hello.greet()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import hello
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/einverne/boost_test/hello.so, 2): Library not loaded: libboost_python.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/einverne/boost_test/hello.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libboost_python.dylib in /Users/einverne/boost_test/hello.so with restricted binary
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17704255/1820217) as a reference.

To my problem, use `otool -L hello.so`:

```
hello.so:
    hello.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.10)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
```

you can see that libboost_python.dylib is not point to the really exist path.

so use this command:

```
install_name_tool -change libboost_python.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib hello.so
```

and run `otool -L hello.so` again:

```
hello.so:
    hello.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.10)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
```

and finally run `python test.py`, I get the result.

Comment: sometimes you want use sudo `sudo install_name_tool -change libboost_python.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib some.so`

Comment: This saved me *hours*. Thank you!!

Comment: @sharmask: When would I want to do that instead? Would it give errors, or would it silently fail without `sudo`?

Comment: @jvriesem: When the file (given in the last argument, ie `some.so`) is only writable by root.  Generally, yes, that should give an error if `install_name_tool` can't write to it.

Answer (score 3):

It is advisable to *change the Boost dynamic libraries themselves* on MacOS instead of changing the executables or other dynamic libraries linked against them. Run the `bash` script given below in the directory that contains your `libboost_XXX.dylib` libraries:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Modify the absolute dylib paths baked into the libraries
for i in *.dylib
do
    FULLPATH=`pwd`/$i
    install_name_tool -id $FULLPATH $i
    echo -change $i $FULLPATH
    done > changes
for i in *.dylib
do
    install_name_tool `cat changes` $i
done
rm changes
```

You will need to do this only once after you built the Boost libraries. No mucking around with the executables linking against them is needed.