# git status gives errors about "dyld: Library not loaded ..."

Tags: git

What does this error mean and how to fix it?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/ldyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced fromibintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gettext
  Reaso: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reasn: image not found
on: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/bin/gettext.sh: line 87:  3166 Abort trap: 6           envsubst "$1"
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gettext
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/bin/gettext.sh: line 87:  3207 Abort trap: 6           envsubst "$1"
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 2.19.0
```

Comment: Have you tried https://superuser.com/a/1112239?

Comment: is this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded/40175799 ?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by upgrading the Homebrew version of node

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew upgrade node
brew link --overwrite node
```

The last part `brew link --overwrite node` is so that `/usr/local/bin/node` is symlinked with the new Homebrew version of node, and not the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappeared after upgrading Xcode and Command Line Tools via the App Store app, and restarting the computer.