# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage, cryptoswift

I'm receiving this error on startup

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift
  Referenced from: /Users/konradwright/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/61734D4D-978B-4BFB-88B2-DBE87771F1A6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F974F048-38F9-4F9A-9988-11EF9B319DD4/Draftboard.app/Frameworks/PusherSwift.framework/PusherSwift
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and I've looked at other solutions.

Here's what I have tried:

- Key Chain Access: up to date
- Deleting Derived Data
- And updating @rpath to have:

  @loader_path/Frameworks

  @executable_path/Frameworks

  @loader_path/../Frameworks

  @executable_path/../Frameworks

I use Carthage to load in CryptoSwift and I don't have any compiler errors.

Comment: Check these links [here](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/issues/427), [here](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/issues/132) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded/40175799).

Comment: @Kamran I updated Carthage and added the frameworks and run scripts and that fixed the error! Thanks!

Comment: Glad the issue is fixed!

Comment: 2 of those links don't work anymore. an answer with context would have been more useful.