# Error creating extension PostGIS in pgAdmin on macOS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin-4, postgis-installation

I'm trying to install postGIS on my macOS.
I already had postgreSQL and pgAdmin4 installed and I just wanted to install the postGIS extension.
I used stuckbuilder to download it and followed the instructions, then I tried to create a new database on pgAdmin4 and create the extension using the following instruction:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

But then I got this error:

> ERROR: could not load library "/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.5.so": dlopen(/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.5.so, 10): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib/postgresql/libgdal.20.dylib
>   Reason: image not found

What does it means and what can I do to fix it?

I already tried other solutions I found here on stackoverflow, but nothing changed. I hope you can help me.

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?  And how did you install PostgreSQL?  And what is "stuckbuilder?"

Comment: Perhaps this helps you further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found