# How to fix "dyld: Library not loaded" error when running composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, bitnami

I am on a bitnami MAMP stack. I am using the php shipped with MAMP as my default PHP installation.

I have installed composer using php scripts:

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Now whenever I type composer in my bash terminal, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /bitnami/mampstackDev-osx-x64/output/common/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/mampstack-7.1.15-0/php/bin/php.bin
  Reason: image not found
```

Seems to be some problem with loading of libcryptolib.

**[UPDATE 03-12-2019]** 
One comment i would like to add is that this problem is happening from the time i changed my default PHP installation from /usr/bin/php to Mampstack PHP. Once i reverted the default php installation it started working

Comment: please clear composer cache and then re try

Comment: Are you on Mac Host? Could this be a similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found

Comment: Is the issue exclusive to Composer? I mean, running `php` from command-line doesn't trigger that message?

Comment: @AshokSongara I am getting the same error when I am typing composer clear cache

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am able to execute PHP cli properly

Comment: composer diagnose using this command may you will get the exact error I think its installation error maybe  or try ```brew upgrade node```

Comment: composer diagnose is returning the same result...it seems the composer program itself is not running

Comment: In the Linux environment, the `ldconfig` command must be run (as super-user) to update the loader cache, which is necessary to resolve library names.  The loader doesn't actually look through the filesystem to find the right file:  it uses the cache.  (It won't find a library that isn't in the cache even if it is in the filesystem.)  Most of the time, this command is run automatically by `make install` scripts, but not every time.  Try `sudo ldconfig` and see if that fixes things. *(First make sure that the library-file IS there, o'course.)*

Comment: By default, composer should be included in `/Applications/mampstack-7.1.15-0/php/bin/composer`. Could you try to load the environment   `/Applications/mampstack-7.1.15-0/use_mampstack` and run `composer --help` then?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is because neither Bitnami MAMP installer nor the `use_mampstack` startup script are setting the correct path to libraries, even though they are bundled and provided in `./common/lib` directory (relative to your MAMP's installation path, for example `/Applications/mampstack-7.2.29-2/`).

To fix the issue, simply create symbolic links to **libcrypto** and **libssl** like this:

```
ln -s /Applications/mampstack-7.2.29-2/common/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
ln -s /Applications/mampstack-7.2.29-2/common/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Of course, adjust library and MAMP stack version names to what you have installed on your system.