# Setting up TURN server; "dyld: Library not loaded, Reason: image not found"

Tags: openssl, webrtc, dyld, turn, coturn

I am trying to set up a TURN server with Coturn, in accordance with [these](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/CoturnConfig) instructions, but I am getting stuck at this step:

> Add the long-term TURN users with the turnadmin utility. For example,
>   this command adds user ninefinger with password youhavetoberealistic,
>   realm north.gov, to the default sqlite database:
>
> `$ sudo turnadmin -a -u ninefingers -r north.gov -p youhavetoberealistic`
>
> Add the admin user(s) to the database, with
>   turnadmin utility. If you added those users, then will be able to
>   connect to the TURN server ports over HTTPS from your browser and
>   perform admin tasks with the web interface.
>
> For example, this command adds the admin user bayaz with password
>   magi:
>
> `$ sudo bin/turnadmin -A -u bayaz -p magi`

In my `turnserver-4.5.0.8` directory, I enter `sudo turnadmin -a -u <some_username> -r -p <some_password>` (not entering a value for -r gives it the default realm, correct?), and I am given the following error message:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libevent_openssl-2.0.5.dylib Reason: image not found`

I have tried adapting answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found) question to my case, but I do not know what the `@executable_path` is, which means I also don't know which libraries I should be using `install_name_tool -change` on and in what order. (My confusion here likely stems either from my not fully understanding how `turnadmin` is trying to go about its business, or from my having no clue what `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib` and `/usr/local/lib/libevent_openssl-2.0.5.dylib` actually are and how they differ from one another.)

Incidentally, the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37131802/9044421) answer to the above-linked question says:

> In the target's `General` tab, there is an `Embedded Binaries field.`
>
> add required `framework` and crash is resolved.

Is this applicable to my case? I do not understand the terms "target" and "framework" (again, this probably has to do with my not understanding what `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib` and `/usr/local/lib/libevent_openssl-2.0.5.dylib` are.)

I also tried `upgrade brew`, but this didn't change anything for me.

I'm running Max OS X.

Edit: May be worth noting that my attempt to set up Coturn is born of step 3 in the webrtc Deployment instructions [here](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc).

Edit 2 (regarding the linked question above): What is the difference between @executable_path/libboost_something.dylib and the value that would be entered as as substitute for the "exefile" example variable?