# gdal dyld: Library not loaded Reason: image not found

Tags: macos, homebrew, gdal, dyld

```
➜  ishan git:(master) ✗ ogr2ogr -f GPKG ./testgpkg.gpkg combining_elevation_coastline_data.csv -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=x -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=y -a_srs 'EPSG:4326'
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.91.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ishansrivastava/miniconda/lib/libgdal.26.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[1]    94711 abort      ogr2ogr -f GPKG ./testgpkg.gpkg combining_elevation_coastline_data.csv -oo
```

I am trying to convert a csv file into a geopackage file

things i tried:

1.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
```

2. 

reinstalled xcode command line tools

3.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261326/7806805

4.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17704255/7806805

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool-classic: can't open file: exefile (No such file or directory)
```

5. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011143/7806805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what finally worked:

```
conda update -c rdonnellyr -c main --all
```

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I think it is enough and it really works.

Comment: @amo the reason it was voted for low quality wasn't its correctness but its ability to inform future readers and help them make an educated decision on using this solution, would it help them or ruin something, explain the solution so it wouldn't be magic, Voodoo or "it just works" and explain the reasoning and use cases for it.