# Eclipse on Mac dyld: Library not loaded: Image not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, shared-libraries

All:

I have successfully set up two projects (Hello and World) in one workspace (HelloWorld).  These are simple projects that are supposed to work together as a main project and a shared library project.  This is the structure:

```
HelloWorld
    Hello
        src
            Hello.cpp
        Debug
            src
            Hello - [x86_64/le]
    World
        src
            World.cpp
            World.h
        Debug
            src
            libWorld.dylib - (x86_64/le]
```

I have followed all instructions and finally was able to get them to compile with no errors.  However, when I try to run the Hello project I receive the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libWorld.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Hello/Debug/Hello
  Reason: image not found
```

I posted the code below.  It is super simple and the problem (I believe) is somewhere in the Eclipse configuration.

Thank you in advance for your help.

-------------------------------------------- **Source Code** ----------------------------------

**Hello.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "World.h"

int main() {
  printf("Hello %s\n", getWorld().c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

**World.cpp**

```
#include "World.h"

std::string getWorld() { return "World"; }
```

**World.h**

```
#include <string>

std::string getWorld();
```

Comment: export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<directory containing libWorld.dylib> before running Hello

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libWorld.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Hello/Debug/Hello
Reason: image not found
```

This means that your program is using a dynamic library called libWorld.dylib, although you linked your dynamic library to your program during compiling. But you have to tell your program where is the dylib in run-time.

There are two solutions:

Solution 1: set up dynamic library environment variables for your project `in Eclipse`:

1.Right click your `project name`, select `Run As->Run Configuration`

2.Under `Environment` tab click `New`

3.Put `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` in `Name` box

4.Put the path where your `libWorld.dylib` file is in `Value` box

For example: 
      if `libWorld.dylib` file is in `/opt/local/lib/my_dylib` folder, than put the path in the `Name` box

Solution 2: set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your bash configuration file

1.Normally in Mac OS, configuration file is `.profile` under `~/` folder, if you don't have this file than create a new file with the same name

2.Edit that file:

> Add this line in your `.profile` file:
>       `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=PATH_TO_YOUR_DYLIB:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
>
> in my example the PATH_TO_YOUR_DYLIB is `opt/local/lib/my_dylib`, so you just add:
>        export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/my_dylib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH 
>   in .profile file

3.Problem solved, in this solution, you don't have to set up dylib path for all eclipse project

PS. DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is an environment variable to specify the path of your dynamic library

Difference between `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s) post