# dyld: Library not loaded: libNiTE2.dylib....Reason: image not found

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors, openni, nite

The library I am trying to use is **NiTE2**, I have successfully include & linked OPENNI2 and the libfreenect driver. Here is the error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libNiTE2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/yangwang/Documents/cinder_projects/basic/xcode/build/Debug/basic.app/Contents/MacOS/basic
  Reason: image not found
```

**NOTE:**
There are quite a few similar questions regarding the same error messages. but none of them helped my case.

A few things I already tried but not working:

- I have tried adding the dylib file into **Embedded Binaries** like this one suggested: [dyld: Library not loaded, Reason: image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455492/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found)
- I also made sure I have included the correct search path for the lib, and properly set it up in **Library Search Path**, like this one suggested:
  [Eclipse on Mac dyld: Library not loaded: Image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855488/eclipse-on-mac-dyld-library-not-loaded-image-not-found)

All openni2 and libfreenect related dylibs are being found with no problem.

Here are images of my settings:

[project hierarchy view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHUcj.png)

[library search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRRTC.png)

XCode v: 9.3.1
Mac os v: 10.13.4

**----UPDATE-----**

I added some **Copy Files** settings into Build Phase, [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S0Gr.png), including everything inside my include and lib folder. This didn't solve my problem ( **yet** ). Then, after build, I went `myapp.app/Contents/MacOS` and used `./myapp` to run the build. And it magically runs and found all libraries! I don't quite understand why though, hope someone can explain.

Comment: I wonder if what library path the executable links against in the end (if it's what you see is in Xcode or not). Does it run in Xcode, but not when double clicking or you get this crash in Xcode directly ? what do you get if you run: `otool -L /Users/yangwang/Documents/cinder_projects/basic/xcode/build/Debug/basic.app/Contents/MacOS/basic | grep nite` ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza  i added some updates.  do they provide more info for you?

Comment: what is the output of `otool -L` against your executable ? My hunch is is it has to do with how the .dylib is referenced (if it's an absolute path, using @rpath, @executable_path, etc.). Can you run the above long command command in Terminal and paste the output ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza  the result is null. nothing fits the filter `nite`

Comment: What does the output look like without the filter ? (`otool -L /Users/yangwang/Documents/cinder_projects/basic/xcode/build/Debug/basic.app/Contents/MacOS/basic`)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza text too long , here is a screencap of it -> https://ibb.co/ky2vXd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libNite2.dylib is linked from the same folder as the basic executable.

You could use `@executable_path`, to point to the dylib: this way, double clicking on the file should work.

It might be possible to change it using `installname_tool`:

`cd /Users/yangwang/Documents/cinder_projects/basic/xcode/build/Debug/basic.app/Contents/MacOS/`

then

`install_name_tool -change libNiTE2.dylib @executable_path/libNiTE2.dylib basic`.

Fingers crossed this will work when you double click the .app file.

You may want to add this as an extra step in Xcode post compile to avoid having to type this every time you change something in code. Something along these lines: bare in mind the screenshot is actually from an OpenFrameworks, not Cinder project, but you should have a similar view in XCode (some variables might be different).

[image: install_name_tool change dylib path post compile]

Another side note: based on your screenshot it looks like OpenNI is linked against from `/usr/local/opt/openni2`(guessing Homebrew symlink). This will work on your machine, but not on another mac unless you install OpenNI2 via homebrew on it as well (otherwise, if the OpenNI libs are copied to the executable you can consider setting executable relative paths for these too).

Comment: i totally understood the intentions of the steps. it looks promising. but it didn't fix it. here is a picture showing the `otool` has be modified and `libNiTE2.dylib` is in place. : https://ibb.co/dSnzSd    same old error msg when running in xcode. and double click .app shows nothing.

Comment: Thank you for giving it a go. I thought that would sort it out. Can you let me know which version of cinder/xcode/OpenNI2 cinder block you're using ? (I'm busy these days, but at some point it would be good to figure out)

Comment: cinder version: 0.9.1,  not using any openni2 cinder block. download the openni2's latest version straight from https://structure.io/openni