# Gazebo on OSX 10.11 fails to start. Library "libOgreTerrain" missing

Tags: macos, installation, ros

I followed the tutorial from the [official guide](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_mac&cat=install) in order to install Gazebo 6, on OSX 10.11. 
But, when I try to run gazebo, I get the following error.
It doesn't find the libOgrePaging library.

```
$ gazebo
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Components/libOgrePaging.1.7.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libOgreTerrain.1.7.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?
Can I install manually this library?

Thank you very much for your time,

Kostas.

Comment: Gazebo 7 on sierra, it is installed but not linked `/usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_2/lib/libOgrePaging.1.7.4.dylib`

Answer (score 2):

After some quest, I solve this issue by doing the following. In my case, I have two libs missing (`libBulletDynamics.2.86.dylib` and `libOgrePaging.1.7.4.dylib`), both installed but not linked.

To look for where are they:

```
find /usr/local/Cellar -name "libOgrePaging.1.7.4.dylib"
```

Add the containing lib to the end of `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/bullet/2.86.1_1/lib:/usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_2/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And source it

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

---

Reference:

- [Is it OK to use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X? And, what's the dynamic library search algorithm with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274)
- [dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: Image not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the correct solution, but it seems to work for me so far.

Go to `/usr/local/Cellar/gazebo6/6.60_2(or whatever version it is)/` and make a folder called `Components`.

After that, go to `/usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4/lib` and copy all of the contents into the components folder, and then gazebo should launch.