# _Unwind_Resume not found when linking to boost statically but not dynamically on osx

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost, qmake

I am working on a shell script to run qmake commands to build a project on OSX.

I was getting this error after updated to Xcode 7.1.2 (which I had to do because nothing would build at all after upgrading to yosemite before I updated XCode):

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__Unwind_Resume", referenced from:
```

It turns out that qmake was generating a makefile with the flag `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` and changing that with `sed` to `10.9` did the trick.

But, now I have a problem caused by linking to 4 or 5 boost libraries (got with homebrew) and another dynamic library (`libbar64.dylib`) that I wrote. Here is the stripped down version of the build script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT="foo"

# to find the dylib
install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../Resources/libbar64.dylib" 

# moc and uic
$QMAKEPATH/uic mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
$QMAKEPATH/moc mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp

# library paths and libs
libpath="-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib -L./"
libs="-lbar64 -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_exception-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt"

# make pro file
$QMAKEPATH/qmake -project
echo 'LIBS +=' $libpath $libs >> $PROJECT.pro

# generate the makefile
$QMAKEPATH/qmake -spec macx-g++ $PROJECT.pro

# kludge
sed -i -e 's/min=10.5/min=10.9/g' Makefile

# make it
make
# put libbar into the resources folder
cp ./libbarl64.dylib $PROJECT.app/Contents/Resources/
```

The problem arises because the shared boost libraries aren't known to `foo` after its built. I could set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the boost directory `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/lib/` but I don't want to do that ([because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s)).

I tried to change my `libs` variable to:

```
libs="-shared -lbar64 -static -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_exception-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt"
```

But now I get the

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__Unwind_Resume", referenced from:
```

error again. Does anyone know how to get around this without swapping environment variables? I never had problems of this kind until the latest OSX updates. I want to link to boost statically, but it seems be in opposition with libgcc_eh.a libarary for some reason. I hate it when Apple updates break my build scripts.

Comment: Are the libraries built 64-bit?

Comment: AFAICT. What puzzles me is that I don't get this error when I link to boost dynamically, but do get it when I link statically. The two versions of the library were both obtained via homebrew and sit in the same directory.

Comment: Maybe try specifying the full path to the 64-but libraries instead of `-llib`. If that works you might need to add something like -m64 somewhere on the command line.

Comment: I'm starting to think that libgcc_eh.a is in fact not the right architecture. I don't really know how to go about correcting this in Mac-land.