# Cannot run a program by clicking on it while I can from Terminal

Tags: c++, macos, dynamic, lib

I'm trying to learn how to build and use dynamic library in a c++ program. Everything is fine and my program run well when I launch it from Terminal (I'm on a mac OS X El Capitan). Surprisingly that's not the case when I try to launch it by clicking on the executable. I get a `dyld: Library not loaded: liblibrary.so`, `Reason: image not found` error.

All my files are in a same repertory. I build them with commands :

```
g++ -c -fPIC A.cpp
g++ -c -fPIC B.cpp
g++ -shared -fPIC A.o B.o -o library.so
g++ main.cpp library.so -o Program
```

Thank's in advance for your help.

I tried the following solutions :

- Add a PATH, both in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- Change the library extention : `library.so` or `library.dylib`
- Add an rpath `g++ main.cpp library.so -Wl,-rpath,. -o Program` and `g++ main.cpp library.so -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/my_dir -o Program`

Comment: When you run in from the command-line, are you in the same directory as the `library.so` file? That's why the system could find the library, because it's in your *current directory*. If it's not in the *current directory* then the system needs to find where the library is, which is done with the [`-rpath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) **linker** option.

Comment: By the way, your main application doesn't have to be built with the `-fPIC` option, only the library.

Comment: Yes I was in the current directory but I previously tried `g++ -Wl,-rpath,. main.cpp library.so -o Program` to link with my current directory and nothing changed.

Comment: The rpath should not be a relative directory, but some absolute path. Please **edit your question** to explain what has been tried

Comment: After following your commands with a trivial program, `otool` reports that it refers to "library.so" (i.e., in `.`).  Using `getcwd()`, I can see that OSX starts double-clicked programs in `~`, not the directory of the executable.  You need to make your rpath reference relative to `@executable_path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Actually, dynamic library creation is different for macOS. What I tried since the beginning is only working for Linux.

So the Mac solution is:

```
g++ -dynamiclib -install_name "absolute_path/library.dylib" A.o B.o -o library.dylib
```

where:

- `-dynamiclib` is the Mac equivalent for `-shared`.
- `-install_name "absolute_path/library.dylib"` create an alias of `library.dylib` for the linker which is necessary to use `library.dylib`.

After that, the traditional command:

```
g++ main.cpp library.dylib -o Program
```

creates the executable if `main.cpp` and `library.dylib` are in the same directory.

The program can then be used everywhere in the system as long as `library.dylib` stays in the same place.

Following the comment of @Ssswift, relative path linking can be achieved with the command:

```
g++ -dynamiclib -install_name "@executable_path/library.dylib" A.o B.o -o library.dylib
```

The library can then follow the executable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to give an explicit [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) (as an absolute path, not a relative one) at compile time (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/yourdir  main.cpp library.so -o Program`), or setup some `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3146274/841108). You could need a `.dylib` suffix, not a `.so` one.

<sup>(I don't have any MacOSX any more, so I forgot the details)</sup>

Comment: I tried all of these solutions but none worked for me.

Comment: Then please edit your question to explain what exactly has been tried