# Install and run MongoDB connector for BI

Tags: mongodb

I have already followed [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/install-bi-connector-macos/) and installed `mongosqld` in my Mac OS. Now, I can see the folder under contents under `bin/mongosqld`.

But, when I followed [this link](https://cube.dev/blog/building-mongodb-dashboard-using-node.js) and launched `/bin/mongosqld`, I got the error:

```
$ bin/mongosqld 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/chengtie/Downloads/mongodb-bi-osx-x86_64-v2.13.4/bin/mongosqld
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install OpenSSL 1.1 if you haven't already.

If the libraries were not installed at `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/` (I believe this is the default location if you install via HomeBrew), you will need to set up the environment so the linker can find them.

See [Is it OK to use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X? And, what's the dynamic library search algorithm with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s)

Comment: i have install mongosql bi connector but how would i run this as background because to start in i have to run this as by typing mongosql in terminal