# How to install IBM db2 cli drivers on mac osx mojave

Tags: macos, db2, ibm-midrange, unixodbc

In order to use db2 with node.js on my mac. I have installed the [db2 drivers - DB2 v11.1.4.5](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli//macos64_odbc_cli.tar.gz).

I also configured my environment paths so that the correct config files will be used by unixODBC
I configured the **odbcinst.ini**, **ODBC.ini** , **db2cli.ini**, and the **db2dsdriver.cfg** files

> The issue is that I get the error below when I run the **iqsl** command or the **db2cli validate** command

**My Error**

```sh
[S1000][unixODBC][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "3".
```

**unixODBC isql command syntax**

```
isql usrProd userid password
```

**db2cli validate command syntax**

```
db2cli validate -dsn alias -connect -user userid -passwd password
```

**Environment path stored in file ~/.bash_profile**

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/odbc_db2/clidriver/bin/
export DB2CLIINIPATH=/usr/local/share/odbc_db2/clidriver/cfg/
export DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=/usr/local/share/odbc_db2/clidriver/cfg/
```

> I have been documenting the steps that I took to install the db2 command line drivers.

[My documentation](https://dev.to/moyarich/install-odbc-on-mac-1b1g-temp-slug-8480010?preview=18b369522aac9d4874d6832eb82f0dd1f684768f70d3180a0458592b69ea3eb2d418e5d0fa308e736e2594a829d24aedab5b3962140e17ec4c1ed9ca)

locations of the IBM DB2 Drivers I have installed:

[Client Version (level/bit): DB2 v11.1.4.5 (special_39510/64-bit)](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli//macos64_odbc_cli.tar.gz)

---

[Client Version (level/bit): DB2 v11.1.1.1 (s1703232000/64-bit)](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Information%2BManagement&product=ibm/Information%20Management/IBM%20Data%20Server%20Client%20Packages&release=11.1.*&platform=Mac%20OSX&function=fixId&fixids=*macos_dsdriver*FP001*&includeSupersedes=0&source=fc)

`UPDATE --- 20200413----`

> I got it to work on my Mac. I did get it to work with Node.js

I contacted a few IBM developers who are working directly on this project, and they gave me access to the proper "IBM i Access ODBC Driver" to connect to the as400 from the mac.
It is being beta tested now. At some point, it should be released. to the general public.

db2cli drivers are not needed, db2cli.ini is not needed:

> IBM has specific odbc drivers for the iseries. I dont have permission
>   to share the drivers with the public, but do know that it will be
>   possible soon for everyone to connect to db2 installed on the iseries

Comment: If you want to connect directly via ODBC to Db2-for-i  on MAC OSX, you can *only* do that currently if you have installed-and-licensed a separate "Db2 Connect" gateway server. The reason is that the driver you chose is only for connecting to Db2-on-Linux/Unix/Windows, __or__  via a Db2-connect gateway to i-series or Z/OS.  IBM currently offers ODBC/.NET/OLE DB/XDA connectivity (which does the protocol conversion without needing a gateway) to i-series  via `IBM i access` solutions only on Linux or Microsoft-Windows. So, retry on Linux/Windows or connect indirectly via a Db2-connect gateway.

Comment: Looks like you might also need to set the [library location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s)

Comment: I made the suggested change and It did not help
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/share/odbc_db2/clidriver/lib/

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work on my Mac and I did get it to work with Node.js

I contacted a few IBM developers who are working directly on this project, and they gave me access to the proper "IBM i Access ODBC Driver" to connect to the as400 from the mac. It is being beta tested now, i assume that at some point, it should be released to the general public.

Note : db2cli drivers are not needed, db2cli.ini is not needed, and setting environment paths are not needed:

> IBM has specific odbc drivers for the iseries. I don't have permission
>   to share the drivers with the public, but do know that it will be
>   possible soon for everyone to connect to db2 installed on the iseries

Answer (score 0):

For IBM DB2 Warehouse on the IBM CLoud you can go to this url
https://your_tenant.cloud.ibm.com/console/#connection/overview

In above replace your_tenant with your tenant id.[image]