# Change dylib search directory in macOS

Tags: macos, go

I was trying out the [godal](https://github.com/airbusgeo/godal) library and wrote a simple script as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/airbusgeo/godal"
)

func main() {
    godal.RegisterAll()
}
```

Running `go run main.go` throws the following error

```
dyld[19569]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgdal.30.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/y5/yh59dj093xn_dz8lm0mhv6lh0000gp/T/go-build1573968352/b001/exe/test
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.30.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgdal.30.dylib' (no such file)
signal: abort trap
```

godal has a dependency on gdal and I had installed it via conda. Due to this, the dylib is located under my conda folder - `/Users/ash/miniconda3/lib` not `/usr/local/lib`.

How can I have the program search for `libgdal.dylib` in `/Users/ash/miniconda3/lib` instead of `/usr/local/lib` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/ash/miniconda3/lib/libgdal.dylib`

You can try this in both the shell where you run `go run ....` or as an  `os.Setenv("GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH", "/Users/ash/miniconda3/lib/libgdal.dylib")`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Ran into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to the miniconda3 lib directory to the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. In your case, that would be:

```
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/ash/miniconda3/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH YourGoExecutable
```

Note: Don't use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, as this will [clobber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41072072/765294) existing path resolution, and mostly likely result in unintended trouble down the line.